# Titanium Appcelerator: Reading a .txt file from local app's resources folder and display the content on a Ti.UI.createScrollView

Tags: text, titanium, appcelerator

Could you please post an example of Titanium Appcelerator: Reading a .txt file from local app's resources folder and display the content of that text file on a Ti.UI.createScrollView?

A very simple example. Thank you.

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

.
.
.

win.add(scrollView1);
```

Comment: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Filesystem+Access+and+Storage#FilesystemAccessandStorage-Storagelocations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'example.txt');
var contents = f.read();

Ti.API.info('Output text of the file: '+contents.text);
```

This will give you the text. You can't simply put the text on the scroll view, you will need a label / textbox etc. set the value of one of those controls to the above print out.

Here is a link to the API, this has every method and sample pieces of code, you will need to research / learn you can't just ask for everything you need.

Would also recommend downloading the kitchen sink demo app as it has just about an example of everthing

Comment: Thank you Muhammad and Simon for your help.

Comment: no problem, if this answer was useful / fixed your issue please up vote it / mark as top answer